# Variable defined with with-statement available outside of with-block?

Tags: python

Consider the following example:

```
with open('a.txt') as f:
    pass
# Is f supposed to be defined here?
```

I have read the language docs (2.7) for with-statement as well as PEP-343, but as far as I can tell they don't say anything on this matter.

In CPython 2.6.5 `f` does seem to be defined outside of the with-block, but I'd rather not rely on an implementation detail that could change.

Comment: The question of whether or not f would be available in the enclosing scope has already been answered. For me the whole concept of context managers clicked when I realized that the concept of a *context* is different to that of *scope*. Here is a link to my website that hopefully helps a little: http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/python.html#context_manager

Comment: Exactly - a context is a matter of changing the current state - file open, file closed or thread locked/unlocked. Device allocated/deallocated. All the variables named in scope are still there - but they will now point to deallocated/closed/unlocked handles.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Yes, the context manager will be available outside the with statement and that is not implementation or version dependent. with statements *do not* create a new execution scope.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation in my opinion so awarding the accepted answer; will give points to Alex and TokenMacGuy for additional helpful info.

Comment: Something one could easily forget if have not worked with Python for a while, the function like indentation, name and stuff suggests that you should not be able to access it and yet you can.

Comment: but how can I avoid this? like I made a context manager and don't want user to access the variable once the with clause ends

Answer (score 32):

the `with` syntax:

```
with foo as bar:
    baz()
```

is approximately sugar for:

```
try:
    bar = foo.__enter__()
    baz()
finally:
    if foo.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()) and sys.exc_info():
        raise
```

This is often useful.  For example

```
import threading
with threading.Lock() as myLock:
    frob()

with myLock:
    frob_some_more()
```

the context manager may be of use more than once.

Comment: Well, lock reuse may or may not (no idea, but it would be a bug if they were different) - but the Python scoping rules will definitely be the same here across implementations.

Comment: this is again not a scoping issue. The scoping will be the same. However, if the implementation of foo.__exit__ puts the thread into a stopped state, then unless lock has an __enter__ that relocks it, the second statement doesn't look like it would do anything useful to the thread locks.

Answer (score 18):

In case `f` is a file, it will be appear closed outside the `with` statement.

For example, this

```
f = 42
print f
with open('6432134.py') as f:
    print f
print f
```

would print:

```
42
<open file '6432134.py', mode 'r' at 0x10050fb70>
<closed file '6432134.py', mode 'r' at 0x10050fb70>
```

You can find the details in [PEP-0343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) under the section *Specification: The 'with' Statement*. [Python scope rules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) (which might be [irritating](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-pitfall-scope.html)) apply to `f` as well.

Comment: I know this, I mentioned it in the question. For CPython 2.6.5 at least. But can you guarantee that this same holds for Jython, IronPython and PyPy?

Comment: Python's scope rules are not always so clear either. Consider this in CPython 2.6.5: `[x for x in [1]]`. `x` is available outside of that. Make it into a generator: `(x for x in [1])`. Now `x` is not available. I seem to recall this got changed in Python 3 so that even with list comprehension `x` would not leak, but I can't find the reference now.

Comment: I searched, but haven't found anything significant for now. Interesting question, though.

Comment: Actually this is not a scope matter - the variable f is still available, but it is now a handle to file in the closed state - the same file that was previously open before. The exit call when the context is left will change this state.

Answer (score 13):

To answer Heikki's question in the comments: yes, this scoping behavior is part of the python language specification and will work on any and all compliant Pythons (which includes PyPy, Jython, and IronPython).