# Please elaborate on the use of `WITH` over `TRY CATCH` in this context

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

To handle connections with SQLite3 I studied the `WITH` keyword and found out it is an alternative to `try,except,finally`. It was said in case of file-handling, 'WITH' automatically handles closing files and I thought similar with the connection as said in [zetcode tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/):

> "With the with keyword, the Python interpreter automatically releases
> the resources. It also provides error handling."

I couldn't figure out why both (inner scope and outer scope) statements work. Shouldn't `WITH` release the connection?

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

with con:    
    cur = con.cursor()    

    cur.execute('SELECT 1,SQLITE_VERSION()')
    data = cur.fetchone()   
    print data        
    
cur.execute('SELECT 2,SQLITE_VERSION()')
data = cur.fetchone()
print data
```

Which outputs:

```
(1, u'3.6.21')
(2, u'3.6.21')
```

I don't know what exactly `WITH` is doing. Please elaborate on the use of `WITH` over `TRY CATCH` in this context. And should connections be opened and closed on each query (I am formulating queries inside a function which I call each time with an argument)?

Comment: Have a read of: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager - that should explain your question

Comment: When using 'with' statement, on exit it commits and do not close the connection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager

> Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions. In the event of an exception, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is committed:

So, the context manager doesn't *release* the connection, instead, it ensures that any transactions occurring on the connection are rolled back if any exception occurs, or committed otherwise... Useful for `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and `INSERT` queries for instance.

Comment: so no releasing of resources or error handling as advertised then?

Comment: The tutorial you're reading is a bit misleading. There is no explicit closure of the connection when using the default context manager. You may want to look at `contextlib.closing`...

Comment: agreed, it actually says.... Note The context manager neither implicitly opens a new transaction nor closes the connection.

Answer (score 24):

In general, a context manager is free to do whatever its author wants it to do when used. Set/reset a certain system state, cleaning up resources after use, acquiring/releasing a lock, etc.

In particular, as [Jon already writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19522634/296974), a database connection object creates a transaction when used as a context manager. If you want to auto-close the connection, you can do

```
with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(':memory:')) as conn:
    with conn as cur:
        data = cur.execute('SELECT 1, SQLITE_VERSION()').fetchone()
        print(data)  # (1, "3.39.3")

    with conn as cur:
        [[two, version]] = cur.execute('SELECT 2, SQLITE_VERSION()')
        print(two, version)  # 2 3.39.3
```

Comment: In python 3, this seems to give `AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47501337/2786884 seems to solve the problem

Comment: @Løiten More or less, yes. This other answer doesn't retrieve data, however. So it doesn't really solve the problem with `.fetchone()`. I don't have a solution at hand currently for that, as I don't have much experience with Py3 and SQlite.

Answer (score 20):

You could also write your own wrapper around sqlite3 to support `with`:

```
class SQLite():
    def __init__(self, file='sqlite.db'):
        self.file=file
    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.file)
        self.conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        return self.conn.cursor()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

with SQLite('test.db') as cur:
    print(cur.execute('select sqlite_version();').fetchall()[0][0])
```

https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html#SECTION000910000000000000000

Comment: is it necessary to do self.conn.commit()? With doesn't commit automatically?

Comment: @cikatomo `with` does only what we tell it to do. The `SQLite` class tells `with` what to do. If you want `with` to commit, you have to do it on `__exit__()`

Comment: Maybe do `return self.conn`. Then you can do `with SQLite('test.db') as conn:` and then create a new cursor for every transaction (`with conn as cur:`) and can omit the `self.conn.commit()` (which anyway should be called in the error-free case only)

Comment: Commit shouldn't do anything if there is nothing valid to commit. You could just wrap the connection but I wanted fast direct access for single access and then forget about the file handle.

Comment: Similar to [bottle Sqlite decorator](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle-sqlite/blob/master/bottle_sqlite.py). See `SQLitePlugin.wrapper()`