# Should I call connect() and close() for every Sqlite3 transaction?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to write a Python module to abstract away database transactions for my application. My question is whether I need to call `connect()` and `close()` for every transaction? In code:

```
import sqlite3

# Can I put connect() here?
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.py')

def insert(args):
    # Or should I put it here?
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.py')
    # Perform the transaction.
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(''' insert args ''')
    conn.commit()
    # Do I close the connection here?
    conn.close()

# Or can I close the connection whenever the application restarts (ideally, very rarely)
conn.close()
```

I have don't much experience with databases, so I'd appreciate an explanation for *why* one method is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the same connection repeatedly. You can also use the connection (and the cursor) as a context manager so that you don't need to explicitly call `close` on either.

```
def insert(conn, args):
    with conn.cursor() as c:
        c.execute(...)
    conn.commit()

with connect('db.py') as conn:
    insert(conn, ...)
    insert(conn, ...)
    insert(conn, ...)
```

There's no reason to close the connection to the database, and re-opening the connection each time can be expensive. (For example, you may need to establish a TCP session to connect to a remote database.)

Comment: Context manager is the way to go, it also gracefully catches and handles exceptions

Comment: If you use the **Connection object** as the expression in the `with` statement, it will automatically commit or rollback transactions, without needing to include `conn.commit()`.  See [Using the connection as a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager)

Comment: as [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9562049/1220835) have pointed out, using `with connect() as connection:` does not automatically close the connection as `with` does not create a new scope. Please adjust your answer.

Comment: or to cite [sqlite3 docs](https://python.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager): "Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions." Note how they don't mention the connection would be closed, because it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

Using a single connection will be faster, and operationally should be fine.

Use the `atexit` module if you want to ensure the closing eventually happens (even if your program is terminated by an exception).  Specifically, `import atexit` at the start of your program, and `atexit.register(conn.close)` right after you `connect` -- note, **no** `()` after `close`, you want to **register** the function to be called at program exist (whether normal or via an exception), **not** to **call** the function.

Unfortunately if Python should crash due e.g to an error in a C-coded module that Python can't catch, or a `kill -9`, etc, the registered exit function(s) may end up not being called.  Fortunately in this case it shouldn't hurt anyway (besides being, one hopes, a rare and extreme occurrence).