# Connecting/closing database once VS doing it everytime I change something - which is better?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is it better open the database in the first lines of the program and close at the end, or should I open it and close every time I insert/delete anything from it? What differences are there?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829010/should-i-call-connect-and-close-for-every-sqlite3-transaction) answer your question?

Comment: Mostly yes, thanks. Even though I would really want to know if there is any difference in anything and what is this difference

Comment: Re-using a single connection is more efficient than repeatedly setting up and tearing down connections.  That is the main difference.