# WindowsError moving sqlite3 database after closing

Tags: python, windows, sqlite

Here's a simplified example of my problem:

```
import os
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('test.db.temp') as db:
    db.executescript('CREATE TABLE foo (bar);')
os.rename('test.db.temp', 'test.db')
```

Output:

```
> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    os.rename('test.db.temp', 'test.db')
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Background: I'm attempting to create a database in an "atomic" way, the simplest way to do that is create the database at a temporary location and then move it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the context manager of the connection object seems not to work.

This way it works:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db.temp')
db.executescript('CREATE TABLE foo (bar);')
db.close()
os.rename('test.db.temp', 'test.db')
```

It is worth investigating why it implements the `__enter__/__exit__` in the first place...

**UPDATE:** From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561832/what-if-i-dont-close-the-database-connection-in-python-sqlite) it looks like the `with` when used with SQLite does a transaction, so your code is similar to:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db.temp')
db.begin_transaction()
db.executescript('CREATE TABLE foo (bar);')
db.commit()
os.rename('test.db.temp', 'test.db')
```

So the db is still obviously opened when renamed. The recommended code would then be something like:

```
with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect('test.db.temp')) as db:
    db.executescript('CREATE TABLE foo (bar);')
os.rename('test.db.temp', 'test.db')
```

Comment: edited your answer to include `contextlib.closing` :)  Real shame that the sqlite api doesn't close the file as part of their contextmanager.

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Nice, thanks! I didn't know about `contextlib`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), **executescript** creates a cursor object. I am guessing the cursor object is not getting destroyed immediately. Try creating a cursor explicitly in the context manager:

```
with sqlite3.connect('test.db.temp') as db:
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar);')
```

Comment: If this is the case, wouldn't the proper fix be to add a `with cur = `... instead of hoping it closes itself sooner? (Note: I don't know the Python bindings of SQLite.)

Comment: I was going off of this example: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/ which seems to work

Comment: Interestingly, this example works on Xubuntu 14.04 but not on Windows 7. You have to add the explicit **db.close()** for it to work on Windows.

Comment: Interesting. The call to rename should succeed regardless of if the file is opened anyway, since Windows supports renaming a file that's currently in use (the process's file handle is not invalidated).

Comment: Yeah sorry, had nothing to do with the cursor.  It in fact repros with just `with sqlite3.connect('test.db.temp'): pass;; os.rename('test.db.temp', 'test.db')`

Comment: @Cameron, the file isn't opened with sharing mode `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`, so it can't be renamed while the handle is open. Neither the C runtime nor Python's io or os modules provide a way to open a file with delete sharing. You need to use `_winapi.CreateFile` or ctypes, but that won't help with the sharing mode used by sqlite3.