The problem with closing the database connection
There is some issue with closing the database connection, but I don't understand why I can't close the access and delete the database afterwards. I tried a lot of time, but I didn`t see information about my error.
I tried to describe the problem with deletion in the delete_database function, but it didn't work out. The error that appears is:
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function delete_database at 0x0000023EA47A8720>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "File name", line 71, in delete_database
    os.remove("University.db")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'University.db

My code
import sqlite3
import os
def create_tables():
    with sqlite3.connect("University.db") as database:
        cursor = database.cursor()

        # Створення таблиць
        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students (
            student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            first_name TEXT,
            last_name TEXT,
            age INTEGER,
            group_id TEXT,
            FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES Groups(group_id)
        )""")

        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Groups (
            group_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            group_name TEXT
        )""")

        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Courses (
            course_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            course_name TEXT
        )""")

        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Teachers (
            teacher_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            first_name TEXT,
            last_name TEXT
        )""")

        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Results (
            result_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            student_id INTEGER,
            subject_id INTEGER,
            teacher_id INTEGER,
            grade INTEGER,
            FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Students(student_id),
            FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES Subjects(subject_id),
            FOREIGN KEY (teacher_id) REFERENCES Teachers(teacher_id)
        )""")

        database.commit()

def add_student(first_name, last_name, age, group_id):
    with sqlite3.connect("University.db") as database:
        cursor = database.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Students (first_name, last_name, age, group_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       (first_name, last_name, age, group_id))
        database.commit()

def get_student_info(student_id):
    with sqlite3.connect("University.db") as database:
        cursor = database.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE student_id = ?", (student_id,))
        student_info = cursor.fetchone()
        return student_info

def get_all_students():
    with sqlite3.connect("University.db") as database:
        cursor = database.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Students")
        all_students = cursor.fetchall()
        return all_students

def delete_database():
    if os.path.exists("University.db"):
        os.remove("University.db")
        print("The database file has been deleted.")
    else:
        print("The database file does not exist.")

atexit.register(delete_database)

create_tables()

while True:
    option = int(input("Select an option:\n1. Information about one student\n2. Information about all students\n3. Exit"))

    if option == 1:
        student_id = input("Enter the student number: ")
        student_info = get_student_info(student_id)
        print(student_info)
    elif option == 2:
        all_students = get_all_students()
        for student in all_students:
            print(student)
    elif option == 3:
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect. Try again!")


This should answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032694/windowserror-moving-sqlite3-database-after-closing
The main problem is that context manager isn't doing what you think it is.

@YoshikageKira so I should add rename to my delete_database function? I try did it, but I have this error again

No. what? where did you get that from. I meant you need to use contextlib.closing to close your database. @Олеr

@YoshikageKira yes, I know. I reformatted the cod to this
    with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect('University.db')) as db:
        db.executescript('CREATE TABLE foo (bar);')
    if os.path.exists("University.db"):
        os.remove("University.db")```

Does it correct?

run your code and you will see if it works.

It wrote that "foo" already exist, but after that I called the os.remove('foo'), it doen`t work

A better way would be to not open database in each function and keep database as global variable and just before deleting the db just call uni_db.close(). If you don't want to use global variable you can create main function and create db variable in main. Then you can pass the db as args to all functions.

@YoshikageKira as I understand, I should give the create_table result as parameter to delete_database ?

So, as I understood i have problem with os.remove("Universidy.db"), because when I run sqlite3.conection("University.db").close() it work without os.remove.
