# how with open statement works when an exception occurs

Tags: python-3.x

Friends,

I was trying to open a file with try/except block.

```
try:
    with open(finput[1], "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if "NQ" in line[:2]:
                nq = int(line[-3:].strip())

except EnvironmentError:
    print(("Oops! File \"{:s}\" does not exist!").format(f))
#    print(("Oops! File \"{:s}\" does not exist!").format(finput[1]))
    sys.exit(0)
```

when I use `finput[1]` in except (i.e. that is commented now), it workes fine and gives the file name as intended.
But if I use `f` (as I have tried to open the file `finput[1]` as `f`), it gives me error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "readspr.py", line 30, in 
        print(("Oops! File \"{:s}\" does not exist!").format(f))
    NameError: name 'f' is not defined

I am not much experienced in python (just know coding, but not how it works.).
So, my explanation to this is:
since, opening of the file as `f` failed, nothing is stored in `f`; and hence it is undefined.

But, on the other hand, it seems, python will try to open the file as `f` and hence, whatever is there in `finput[1]` is assigned to `f` as variable string and python has failed to open the file `f`.

I am not sure what is the case here. I tried to understand it from many piece in internet (i.e. [7.2.1 of this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012488/what-is-the-python-with-statement-designed-for) among others) but just found what I use it for: `simplifying exception handling`.

It will be of help to me if you kindly explain why it does not take `f` as exception.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't actually one of scope (see [Variable defined with with-statement available outside of with-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432355/variable-defined-with-with-statement-available-outside-of-with-block)). The problem is that if an exception happens inside `open`, the `as f` statement is never executed, and thus `f` is not yet defined. If the failure happened *inside* the `with` block, then `f` would still be a valid reference.

In other words, there's nothing special about the `with` statement here. Your particular case is semantically equivalent to trying to do the following:

```
try:
    f = open(filename)
except EnvironmentError:
    # Trying to use f here is invalid, since it was never defined if open failed
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, i have one problem in getting this completely. Is there any way that `with` block  fails when the `open` block is ok?

Comment: The `with EXP as VAR:` syntax is part of the [language specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), so if that failed it would be a pretty serious bug in a Python implementation. Not really sure if that's exactly what you're asking though. If you mean 'can code that happens inside the indented scope of the `with` statement `raise`', then of course, just like it can anywhere else inside a python program. `f` would still be defined in that case though.

Comment: To be more clear, the reason you wrap `open` in a `with` is so that `File.close()` is called automatically on exit from the `with` statement's scope, whether that point is reached because the code block completed successfully or because it threw an exception. [Context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) are used to ensure that resources aren't leaked/are always cleaned up even in the event of exceptions being thrown, that's their primary purpose.