# Is NpzFile closing itself when used as a context manager?

Tags: python, numpy, file-descriptor, contextmanager, resource-leak

In docstring of `numpy.load()` I have found the following warning:

> For `.npz` files, the returned instance of NpzFile class must be closed to avoid leaking file descriptors.

I noticed, that the returned `NpzFile` object has both `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods.

Would it take care of closing it automatically if i use it like this:

```
>>> with numpy.load('my_mile.npz') as data:
...     A = data['A']
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Using a `with` statement will close the file-like object. Here's an example, directly from [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html):

```
with load('foo.npz') as data:
    a = data['a']
```

Comment: Shame on me, I missed it. Thanks! :-)

Comment: If I use this, I still see the `data` object after the context. I can use its methods (like `.keys()`) and get the correct output, but if I want to access the actual array with `data[a]` it prints some internal numpy error.
Is it intended behavior to be able to access the object like that?

Comment: @clemisch See accepted answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432355/variable-defined-with-with-statement-available-outside-of-with-block

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**

Yes, it would close the file object automatically after the context ends since an NpzFile object has both `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods (see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4b3ddd74610d1975e0d0eb9c32df2a2d54c8dafd/numpy/lib/npyio.py)).

**Long Answer**

After the closing of the scope of the `with expression as var` context manager, the `var` still remains as an object outside the context manager. However, *in case of* `numpy.load()`*, the file descriptor* `var` *is not accessible outside the scope of the context manager.*
Consider the following example:

```
# Creating a dictionary of data to be saved using numpy.savez
data_dict = {'some_string': 'StackOverflow',
'some_integer': 10000,
'some_array': numpy.array([0,1,2,3,4])
}

# Saving the data
numpy.savez(file='./data_dict.npz', **data_dict)

# Loading the 'data_dict' using context manager
with numpy.load('data_dict.npz') as dt:
    string_ = dt['some_string']
    integer_ = dt['some_integer']
    array_ = dt['some_array']
# OR
with numpy.load('data_dict.npz') as dt:
    dt_ = dict(dt) # if you want the entire dictionary to be loaded as is
```

If you now attempt to access the file descriptor outside the context manager, it will simply return the NpzFile object with its memory address as below:

```
>>> dt
Out[]: <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile at 0x7ffba63bb7c0>
```

However, as should be expected, you will not be able to access any of its properties or attributes. You get `AttributeError`, for instance, when you do:

```
>>> dt['some_string']
Out[]: Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
File ".../site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 249, in __getitem__
    bytes = self.zip.open(key)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'open'
```

This is because, after the end of the with context manager, the NpzFile object's `self.zip` variable gets assigned `None` value (see `def close(self):` in the first URL above, which gets called in the dunder `__exit__()`)

**NOTE 1:** `dt.keys()` returns (as expected) a KeysView object and performing `list(dt.keys())` gives you a list of the keys' names of `dt`: `['some_string', 'some_integer', 'some_array']`. However, one still cannot access the values (outside the scope of the context manager) that were stores on these keys (inside the scope of the context manager).

**NOTE 2:** I have deliberately used a dictionary containing non-numpy-array *values* just to show that it is possible to store such dictionaries using `numpy.savez()`. However, **this is not a recommended method of storing such data.**