# Python "with statement" works in console, but not in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

**In a Spyder iPython console:**

```
print(sys.version)
3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
```

**and in a Ubuntu GNOME terminal 3.18.3:**

```
rappleto:~$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
```

*so identical versions and builds of Python*

**In Spyder:**

```
In [4]: with open("pid.cpp") as pidcpp:
   ...:     data=pidcpp.read()
   ...: print(data)
   ...: 
// pid.cpp - author: rappleto
#include <PID_v1.h>
...
```

**in terminal:**

```
>>> with open("pid.cpp") as pidcpp:
...     data=pidcpp.read()
... print(data)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print(data)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there some special way to end a "with" statement in the terminal?

Comment: Interestingly, putting the `print` statement inside the `with` block seems to make things work fine, even though `with` blocks are not supposed to have a different scope (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: [This answer on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6432414/1090302) is possibly related.

Comment: The `...` prompt means the interpreter is expecting you to add to the previous block (your `with` block). Add an extra newline before the `print` and it should run the `with` block and bring you back to the `>>>` prompt, where you can proceed with the `print`. (At least in the standard python interactive interpreter... I've never used Spyder and can't speak to its prompts.)

Comment: In Python's built-in prompt, you have to terminate a multi-line statement by entering a blank line, before you can start a new top-level (unindented) statement.  This has nothing specifically to do with the `with` statement.

Comment: @jasonharper and glibdud: Seems like you're right!