# Tensorflow sessions - scope of a session context?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scope

```
import tensorflow as tf

...

with tf.Session() as sess:
    output = sess.run(result)
    print(output)

print(output)
```

Why does the last line work? Isn't `output` out of scope since it was declared inside the generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python `with` does not have scoping like methods, this post explains it more clearly
[Variable defined with with-statement available outside of with-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432355/variable-defined-with-with-statement-available-outside-of-with-block)

To save you some time

```
the context manager will be available outside the with statement and that is not implementation or version dependent. with statements do not create a new execution scope.
```